# Where can I find an elementary small-step structural operational semantics for closures?

Tags: reference-request, pl.programming-languages, semantics, compilers

*Lexical closures* are an implementation technique in languages with first-class functions.

I'm interested in a simple operational description of function closures. Does anyone know of such a description?

Comment: Uhm, ask your advisor, the inventor of SOS?

Comment: You are relentless.

Comment: Is there any specific difficulty that prevents you from writing down a small-step SOS yourself?

Comment: I *know* what you're up to!

Comment: I hope so, although this question is unrelated to that.

Answer (score 5):

Is chapter 29 of Bob Harper's [book](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf) what you are looking for?

Comment: No. This is the standard CK-machine style semantics I'm familiar with. From PL-implementation lore, I know that having lexical closures is standard practice. I was wondering whether there is a semantic account which highlights them formally.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your title & question to clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: No, he should write his thesis and talk to his advisor. Or make his advisor use StackExchange.

Answer (score 4):

Closures form an important concept that I try to teach in my undergraduate Programming Languages class.  You can find my [lecture notes](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~udr/popl/index.html) online.

The Handout 8 shows big step semantics using environments and closures.  The Handout 9 shows my flavour of the SECD machine.  (The latter didn't work all that well for teaching purposes because the students got lost in detail and didn't develop good intuitions.  So I switched to big-step semantics.)

Neither of these is what you are asking for, but perhaps they could form a starting point?